# SELECT * FROM (SELECT ...ORDER BY .. LIMIT)

Tags: mysql

Есть MySQL запрос, выглядит так:

```
 SELECT `temp`.* 
FROM (SELECT `price`.`Code`,`price`.`Name`,`price`.`Warranty`,`price`.`Price`,(@rownum:=@rownum+1)as num 
      FROM (SELECT @rownum:=0) AS initialisation,`price`    
      ORDER BY `price`.`Price` LIMIT 41) AS temp WHERE `num`>=21 and `num`<41
```

Мне нужно отсортировать товар по цене и взять из отсортированного 20 последовательных элементов. В некоторых случаях вариант с ORDER BY ... LIMIT работает, в некоторых -нет. Не могу понять как в таком случае поступить.

Comment: Mysql не поддерживает limit  подзапросах (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/subquery-restrictions.html). Зачем такой запрос? Если вы точно описали задачу, то вам просто нужно сделать `select` из `price` с `order by` и `limit 20 offset 20`. Зачем всё остальное?

Comment: Спасибо за помощь!